# SQL Query Select help, monthly report

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and I need help to make a view from a table in my SQL Server. I have a sales table and need to have a monthly sales report with distinct clientid.

This is what my sales table looks like:

```
ID   Name   Amount   Date 
 1   James    300.00  29-09-2015
 1   James    250.00  30-09-2015
 4   Carl     100.00  30-09-2015
 5   Peter    500.50  01-10-2015
 5   Peter    300.00  25-10-2015
```

Desired output:

```
ID   Name   Total    Month/Year
 1    James  550.00   September 2015
 4    Carl   100.00   September 2015
 5    Peter  800.50   October 2015
```

Comment: Anything you've tried already?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    Name, 
    SUM(Amount) AS Total,
    DATENAME(mm, [Date]) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy, [Date]) AS Month_Year
FROM
    <sales table>
GROUP BY 
    ID,
    Name,
    DATENAME(mm, [Date]) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy, [Date])
ORDER BY
    ID,
    Name,
    DATENAME(mm, [Date]) + ' ' + DATENAME(yy, [Date])
```

Aggregating data to produce totals is a very common scenario in SQL, but you should probably start off learning the basics. There are plenty of online resources for this e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    Name, 
    SUM(Amount) AS Total, 
    DATENAME( MONTH , DATEADD( MONTH , DATEPART(MONTH, Date) , -1 )) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, Date) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS "Month/Year"
FROM SALES_TABLE
GROUP BY 
    ID, Name, DATEPART(YEAR, Date), DATEPART(MONTH, Date)
```